# python for loop optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, numba

I'm new to python, I'm trying to find which ever combination gives me the expected value by running four for loop which takes forever to run. Is there a way to optimise it? It seems numba is a good tool but submit will return a dataframe which makes it non-suportable by numba.. Keen to take advice for you! Thanks.

** submit will output a dataframe as follow:

| quantity | product | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | standard | purchase |

```
def submit(ords):
    resp = requests.post("", data=ords.to_json())

    if resp.status_code != 200:
       print(resp.text)
    else:
       return pd.read_json(resp.text)


def order(vendor, send_ts_ms, quantity, product):
    ords = pd.DataFrame({
        "vendor": [vendor],
        "send_ts_ms": [send_ts_ms],
        "quantity": [quantity],
        "product": [product],
    })

return submit(ords)["result"][0]


def get_data(vendor):
        for i in range(-1000,1000):
            for j in range(1, 100000):
                for k in ["platinum","first class","standard","economy"]:   
                    #Parameters for simulation
                    reps = 10
                    outcome = {"no_such_product": 0, "no_stock": 0, "purchased": 0, "unknown_error": 0}
                    for _ in range(reps): outcome[order(vendor, i, j, k)]+=1
    
                    value = j * p_type[k]
                
                    success_rate = outcome["purchased"]/10
                    EV = value * success_rate
                    print(i, j, k, outcome, EV)
```

Comment: What is `order(vendor, i, j, k)`?

Comment: i have updated it with more information. Thanks @crayxt

Comment: I don't think the `for` loops are the main issue here.

Comment: Looks like you are structuring your code around the tools and not the data structure. The ```for``` loop will be slow, it iterates 8 billion times. ```submit``` returns a dataframe because you have used pandas to parse the data. Smaller json module options exist and you might get a significant improvement from returning the part of the json you use rather than the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Numba` won't help you here. `Numba` is generally really useful for simulations, however you are trying to speed up post requests, not calculations. `Numba` doesn't support `requests` so this won't work.

The biggest improvement in performance is for you is hidden in not using pandas. You really don't need it here so just don't. Following code doesn't make use of pandas but simply uses dictionaries instead. Not creating a new dataframe in `order` and `submit` every single simulation saves time.

That being said, the thing your performance hinges on the most will be the post requests. I'm hoping you are requesting responses from your own or some local website, otherwise this reads like a DoS script. You should get blocked in no time.

```
import json

def submit(ords):
    resp = requests.post("", json=ords)

    if resp.status_code != 200:
        print(resp.text)
    else:
        return json.loads(resp.text)


def order(vendor, send_ts_ms, quantity, product):
    ords = {
        "vendor": vendor,
        "send_ts_ms": send_ts_ms,
        "quantity": quantity,
        "product": product,
    })

    return submit(ords)["result"][0]

results_dict = {}

def get_data(vendor):
    for i in range(-1000,1000):
        for j in range(1, 100000):
            for k in ["platinum","first class","standard","economy"]:   
                #Parameters for simulation
                reps = 10
                outcome = {"no_such_product": 0, "no_stock": 0, "purchased": 0, "unknown_error": 0}
                for _ in range(reps): 
                    outcome[order(vendor, i, j, k)]+=1
    
                value = j * p_type[k]
                
                success_rate = outcome["purchased"]/10
                EV = value * success_rate
                results_dict[str(i) + '_' + str(j) + '_' + str(k)] = (outcome, EV)
```

Also using `print` takes a lot of extra time. I'm assuming you are saving the results in a dictionary anyways, I just created one to make sure however.